# Debian..Can't format and mount external HDD

Tags: debian, ext4, raspbian, fdisk, mkfs

I have been trying to format my 640GB external Hard Drive in command-line and can't seem to get it working.

I have done the following in order:

`sudo fdisk /dev/sda`

(Deleted any partitions, created a new partition, toggled partition type (tried multiple, but not sure the best?), then wrote the partition and printed to make sure it was correct.

I then created the ext4 filesystem using: `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`

I tried to mount the partition using: `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt/640-hdd -o gid=XXXX,uid=XXXX`

I then was given a mount error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
    missing codepage or helper program, or other error
    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
    dmesg | tail  or so
```

Any recommendations?

FSTAB info:

```
/dev/sda1       /mnt/640-hdd    ext4    defaults,uid=bwhite94,gid=bwhite94      0       0
```

Comment: Try using gparted

Comment: Were there any errors on the `mkfs.ext4` command? Did you check `dmesg` as the error suggests?

Comment: mkfs.ext4 does not give any errors. It was giving a "Unrecognized mount option 'gid=1004' or missing value" error while trying to mount, so I removed that and bingo.. that worked. Now when I reboot, it's not mounting automatically. I'll edit the main question with info from my fstab.

Comment: eliminate gid and uid and use `mount -a`  then check dmesg.

Comment: When I ran `mount -a` (unchanging fstab) dmesg shows the following: "(sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode." And `df` shows the hard drive mounted. But at boot it does not mount.

Comment: Ah! I see the issue. Thanks @MohsenPahlevanzadeh for the tip. I removed the uid and gid from the fstab file and it works at boot. Since I am running an **ext4** filesystem, it's unnecessary to assign ownerships, as this filesystem does that appropriately, unlike vfat.